# Find day difference between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes one is failures dataframe and the other is maintenance dataframe.

I want to find the number of days difference between the records of both these dataframes based on some conditions.

Condition is-

1. There are multiple machineIDs and component numbers `comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4`. So, the operation needs to be performed on each
   machineID and component number such that for every machineID and its component number I have the day difference between failure and maintenance date.
2. First remove duplicate dates from
   maintenance dataframe.
3. Maintenance date should be older than failure
   date and there can be multiple dates from maintenance dataframe
   which are older than failures date.
4. So, averaging out after finding
   their difference and appending it in the failures dataframe as a new
   column.

The failures dataframe is-

```
            datetime        machineID   failure
0          2021-02-04           1        comp3
1          2021-03-21           1        comp1
2          2021-04-05           1        comp4
3          2021-05-05           1        comp3
4          2021-05-20           1        comp2
5          2021-06-04           1        comp4
6          2021-06-19           1        comp2
7          2021-08-03           1        comp3
8          2021-08-03           1        comp4
9          2021-11-01           1        comp4
```

And this is the maintenance dataframe

```
    datetime        machineID   comp
0   2020-07-01          1      comp4
1   2020-09-14          1      comp1
2   2020-09-14          1      comp2
3   2020-11-13          1      comp3
4   2021-01-05          1      comp1
5   2021-01-20          1      comp1
6   2021-02-04          1      comp3
7   2021-02-19          1      comp3
8   2021-03-06          1      comp3
9   2021-03-21          1      comp1
```

I am taking an example from `failures dataframe` for `index 1` with `machineID 1`, `datetime 2021-03-21` and `failure of Component 1`. Now, if see for the same machineID and component1 in maintenance dataframe, there are 3 dates which are older than the one in failures dataframe i.e., `2021-03-21`. Now, I want to calculate day difference of 2021-03-21 from all these 3 dates of maintenance dataframe and average it out and append it the same index of failure dataframe.

failure datetime- `2021-03-21`

maintenance datetime- `2020-09-14; 2021-01-05; 2021-01-20`

Corresponding day difference- `188 days, 75 days; 60 days.`

Average of these 3- `(188+75+60)/3= 108 days.`

This is something I want-

```
            datetime        machineID   failure     day_dif

1          2021-03-21           1        comp1       108 days
```

Similarly for `component 2, 3 and 4`

Edit1- As per @oskros answer, I am getting this error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1028                 result, _ = self.grouper.aggregate(
-> 1029                     block.values, how, axis=1, min_count=min_count
   1030                 )

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in aggregate(self, values, how, axis, min_count)
    580         return self._cython_operation(
--> 581             "aggregate", values, how, axis, min_count=min_count
    582         )

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in _cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis, min_count, **kwargs)
    510 
--> 511         func, values = self._get_cython_func_and_vals(kind, how, values, is_numeric)
    512 

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in _get_cython_func_and_vals(self, kind, how, values, is_numeric)
    410         try:
--> 411             func = self._get_cython_function(kind, how, values, is_numeric)
    412         except NotImplementedError:

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py in _get_cython_function(self, kind, how, values, is_numeric)
    385             raise NotImplementedError(
--> 386                 f"function is not implemented for this dtype: "
    387                 f"[how->{how},dtype->{dtype_str}]"

NotImplementedError: function is not implemented for this dtype: [how->max,dtype->object]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1060                     # unwrap DataFrame to get array
-> 1061                     assert len(result._data.blocks) == 1
   1062                     result = result._data.blocks[0].values

AssertionError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-02d194427401> in <module>
      1 # 1) Remove duplicates in maintenance dataframe, by getting the latest maintenance date
      2 #    for each combination of machineID and comp
----> 3 maint_df = maint.groupby(['machineID', 'comp']).max().reset_index()
      4 
      5 # 2) Merge the two dataframes so we have maintenance and failure dates for each

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in f(self, **kwargs)
   1376                 # try a cython aggregation if we can
   1377                 try:
-> 1378                     return self._cython_agg_general(alias, alt=npfunc, **kwargs)
   1379                 except DataError:
   1380                     pass

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1002     ) -> DataFrame:
   1003         agg_blocks, agg_items = self._cython_agg_blocks(
-> 1004             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count
   1005         )
   1006         return self._wrap_agged_blocks(agg_blocks, items=agg_items)

/anaconda/envs/sklearnEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1065 
   1066             finally:
-> 1067                 assert not isinstance(result, DataFrame)
   1068 
   1069                 if result is not no_result:

AssertionError:
```

The datatypes of `maintenance dataframe` is

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1038 entries, 0 to 1046
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   Asset      1038 non-null   object        
 1   Type       1038 non-null   object        
 2   datetime   1038 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 3   machineID  1038 non-null   int64         
 4   comp       1038 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 48.7+ KB
```

Comment: can you add an example of the desired dataframe in the output  ?

Comment: @mrCopiCat I have added a sample row as output with some explanation. Please check and if want more detail, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we defined your maintenance dataframe as `maint_df` and your failure dataframe as `fail_df`, the following code should do the trick

```py
# 1) Remove duplicates in maintenance dataframe, by getting the latest maintenance date
#    for each combination of machineID and comp
maint_df = maint_df.groupby(['machineID', 'comp']).max().reset_index()

# 2) Merge the two dataframes so we have maintenance and failure dates for each 
#    combination
fail_df = fail_df.rename(columns={'failure': 'comp'})  # Rename column allowing the merge
merged = maint_df.merge(fail_df, 
                        on=['machineID', 'comp'], 
                        suffixes=('_maintenance', '_failure'))

# 3) Filter out rows where maintenance date isn't older than failure date
merged = merged[merged['datetime_maintenance'] < merged['datetime_failure']]

# 4) Calculate the day difference between the two dates. 
#    NB: This assumes your date columns are strings - if they are already date objects, 
#    you can remove the strptime
merged['diff_days'] = merged.apply(
    lambda x: (dt.datetime.strptime(x.datetime_failure, '%Y-%m-%d') - 
               dt.datetime.strptime(x.datetime_maintenance, '%Y-%m-%d')).days, 
    axis=1)

# 5) Average the day difference across machineID and comp
print(merged.groupby(['machineID', 'comp']).mean())
```

Comment: I am getting this error on line 3. `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'float'`. My datetime is also of type `object` so how do I convert datetime object column to datetime?

Comment: I am answering that in the comments within the code in my reply

Comment: Yeah I saw it. Also the code was running fine yesterday but suddenly it stopped working with some function error which I have updated in the question. Can you please have a look there.

Comment: its probably because you have more columns in your dataframe than in above example, and the additional columns cannot take a "max" value.. so what you could do is filter the maintenance dataframe to only doing a max group on the date column